# Mixed integer programming: variable assignment per condition (if then else)

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, scientific-computing, integer-programming

I am relatively new to (mixed) integer programming and got stuck with the formulation of a constraint.

In my simplified model I have one Parameter and two Variables that are positive Reals having the value 321 as upper bound. The logic I want to express is here:

```
if Parameter > Variable1:
    Variable2 = Variable1
else:
    Variable2 = Parameter

**edit** (while Variable1 is always >= Variable2)
```

Is it actually possible to describe this using linear in(equalities)?

If it helps:  For the implementation I am using Python, Pyomo and the newest gurobi solver.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: Setting `Variable2` equal to min *or* max of `Variable1` and `Parameter`.**

**`min(Parameter,Variable1)`:**

If you are sure that `Variable2` "wants" to be small in the objective function, then you just need to require `Variable2` to be less than or equal to both `Parameter` and `Variable1`:

```
Variable2 <= Variable1
Variable2 <= Parameter
```

**`max(Parameter,Variable1)`:**

If you are sure that `Variable2` "wants" to be large in the objective function, then you just need to require `Variable2` to be greater than or equal to both `Parameter` and `Variable1`:

```
Variable2 >= Variable1
Variable2 >= Parameter
```

**In either case:**

If there's a chance that it will be optimal to set `Variable2` to something strictly less than `min(Parameter,Variable1)` / strictly greater than `max(Parameter,Variable1)`, then you will also (in addition to the constraints above) need to introduce a new binary variable that equals 1 if `Parameter > Variable1`:

```
Parameter - Variable1 <= M * NewVar
Variable1 - Parameter <= M * (1 - NewVar)
```

where `M` is a large number. So, if `Parameter > Variable1` then `NewVar` *must* equal 1, while if `Parameter < Variable1` then `NewVar` *must* equal 0.

**`min(Parameter,Variable1)`:**

Introduce constraints that ensure `Variable2 >= min(Parameter,Variable1)`:

```
Variable2 >= Parameter - M * NewVar
Variable2 >= Variable1 - M * (1 - NewVar)
```

So, if `Parameter > Variable1` then `NewVar = 1`, the first constraint has no effect, and the second says `Variable2 >= Variable1`.  If `Parameter < Variable1` then `NewVar = 0`, the first constraint says `Variable2 >= Parameter`, and the second constraint has no effect.

**`max(Parameter,Variable1)`:**

Introduce constraints that ensure `Variable2 <= max(Parameter,Variable1)`:

```
Variable2 <= NewVar * Parameter + M * (1 - NewVar)
Variable2 <= Variable1 + M * NewVar
```

So, if `Parameter > Variable1` then `NewVar = 1`, the first constraint says `Variable2 <= Parameter`, and the second constraint has no effect. If `Parameter < Variable1` then `NewVar = 0`, the first constraint has no effect, and the second says `Variable2 <= Variable1`.

**In either case:**

Note that `M` should be as small as possible while still ensuring that triggering the `M` in the constraint makes the constraint non-binding. I think it's sufficient to set it equal to the largest value that `|Parameter - Variable1|` can possibly get. In general these "big-Ms" weaken the formulation and result in longer solve times, so you always want them as small as possible.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! 

I completely forgot to mention that Variable1 must be >= Variable2 (I'll add that to the question). So the solution that Variable2 must be >= max(Parameter,Variable1) does not work in my case.

Cheers
Cord

Comment: But your idea to select the maximum of a variable and a parameter using a big-M constraint is interesting. Is it also possible to select the minimum of a variable and a parameter? In this case I could just solve my problem like this: 
    Variable2 = min(Variable1, Parameter)

Comment: Oops I misinterpreted the OP. You want `Variable2 = min(Variable1, Parameter)` but I gave you `...=max(...)`. I will edit my answer. (If  `Variable2 = min(Variable1, Parameter)` then `Variable1 >= Variable2` always holds.)

Comment: Meanwhile, I could solve the "minimum problem" on my own starting from your "big-M-Max-Formulation". The equations look like yours but my assignment is formulated differently: 
    `Variable2 = Variable1 * (1-NewVar) + Parameter * NewVar`.

Since this leads to a quadratic term it can be linearized like described [here](http://orinanobworld.blogspot.de/2010/10/binary-variables-and-quadratic-terms.html).

Thanks a lot, you saved my week, grendelsdad !!

Comment: Your linearized assignment constraint is probably the same basic idea as my constraints. Anyway, glad I could help.

Comment: P.S. don't forget to accept my answer if you like it :)

Comment: Yes, actually it leads to the same form! Works perfectly :)